# how to store blade view as string

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, fetch-api

I want to generate a blade view and store it into a variable that will be used by a `fetch` function.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

View file `/views/flight/show-data.blade.php` :

```
@dd($data)
<div class="my-3">
  @if (count($data))
    <div class="fw-bold">found some data</div>
  @else
    <p>no data.</p>
  @endif
</div>
```

Controller file `FlightController.php` :

```
// other code
function fetchData()
{
  $result['data'] = [
    0 => [ 'name' => 'andre' ],
  ];
  $result['message'] = 'hello world';
  $result['view'] = view('flight.show-data')->with('data', $result)->render(); // causes error
  $result['view'] = '<p>Hello World</p>'; // if switched with this then the error doesn't occur

  return $result;
}
```

script :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#form-cari-flight');
    const btnCariFlight = form.querySelector('#btnCariFlight');

    const mainContentDiv = document.querySelector('#main-content');
    mainContentDiv.innerHTML = '';

    btnCariFlight.addEventListener('click', function() {
        mainContentDiv.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>';
        
        const queryString = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)).toString()

        let url = '/getFlightData?' + queryString;
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json() )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('error', err);
            });
    });
    // end form.addEventListener('submit'
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you try to parse HTML as JSON? Did you check what Laravel returns?

Comment: yes. If i used a simple HTML string in the 'view', then it returns this `res 
Object { message: "hello world", data: (1) […], view: '<p>Hello World</p>'}`

Comment: Check the response in the Network tab of your browser. The error is complaining about the very first character of the response, so you need to check what the actual response is.

Comment: Instead of `return $result`, try using Laravel's built-in logic, i.e. `return response()->json(['result' => $result], 200)`. That will force your rendered view to be returned as a `JSON` object, accessible via `response.result`. Also, consider removing that `@dd()`; that is a "Dump and Die" statement, which would prevent the rest of the HTML below it from being rendered anyway.

Comment: wow, thanks for the tips.